# BigCommerce API Product Import Error: Sorry, something went wrong. Go to product list

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm importing products via the API. The import runs well (no errors), but following the import, whenever I select to EDIT one of the imported products from the product list, I get the following error:

***Sorry, something went wrong.
Go to product list***

I assume something is wrong with the import data I sent, but without further information I don't know where to start looking for the issue.

**For reference, below is the JSON POST data for one of the imported products:**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Calla Lily & Foliage Silk Flower Centerpiece
    [type] => physical
    [sku] => FLB108-WG
    [description] => Lots of HTML shortened to make this code more vieweable
    [weight] => 0
    [price] => 159.00
    [brand_id] => 38
    [inventory_level] => 0
    [inventory_warning_level] => 1
    [is_free_shipping] => 
    [is_visible] => 1
    [layout_file] => product.html
    [upc] => 848644000167
    [availability] => disabled
    [custom_url] => Array
        (
            [url] => 
            [is_customized] => 
        )
 
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
        )
 
    [bulk_pricing_rules] => Array
        (
        )
 
    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [is_thumbnail] => 1
                    [sort_order] => 1
                    [image_url] => https://www.petals.com//files/imagesSF/product/750/flb108-wg_zoom.jpg
                    [description] => white green calla lily & foliage silk centerpiece, velvety texture, natural appearance green foliage, black stones in acrylic water in heavy 6" square tapered glass vase
                )
 
        )
 
    [variants] => Array
        (
        )
 
    [inventory_tracking] => product
    [custom_fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => pageId
                    [value] => 47
                )
 
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => notice
                    [value] => FLB108-WG
                )
 
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => summaryImage
                    [value] => /files/imagesSF/product/165/flb108-wg_cat.jpg
                )
 
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => product_productName
                    [value] => Calla Lily & Foliage
                )
 
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => product_title
                    [value] => Calla Lily & Foliage 
                )
 
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [name] => product_productNumber
                    [value] => FLB108-WG
                )
 
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [name] => product_catalogNumber
                    [value] => FLB108-WG
                )
 
            [7] => Array
                (
                    [name] => product_imagePath
                    [value] => files/imagesSF/product/165/flb108-wg_cat.jpg
                )
 
            [8] => Array
                (
                    [name] => imageBurst
                    [value] => /files/imagesSF/global/bursts/new-bestseller-icon-burst-105.jpg
                )
 
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [name] => acrylicWater
                    [value] => 1
                )
 
            [10] => Array
                (
                    [name] => recipeLocation
                    [value] => right
                )
 
            [11] => Array
                (
                    [name] => prodType
                    [value] => standard
                )
 
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [name] => childTitle
                    [value] => Calla Lily & Foliage
                )
 
            [13] => Array
                (
                    [name] => expShip
                    [value] => 1
                )
 
            [14] => Array
                (
                    [name] => imageBurstLink
                    [value] => /files/filesSF/popups/express-shipping.html
                )
 
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [name] => mobile_name
                    [value] => Calla Lily & Foliage
                )
 
            [16] => Array
                (
                    [name] => googleTitle
                    [value] => Silk Calla Lily Flower Centerpiece with Foliage
                )
 
        )
 
)
```

**Below is the response from BC:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 234
            [name] => Calla Lily & Foliage
Silk Flower Centerpiece
            [type] => physical
            [sku] => FLB108-WG
            [description] => Again reduced for your viewing pleasure
            [weight] => 0
            [width] => 0
            [depth] => 0
            [height] => 0
            [price] => 159
            [cost_price] => 0
            [retail_price] => 0
            [sale_price] => 0
            [map_price] => 0
            [tax_class_id] => 0
            [product_tax_code] => 
            [calculated_price] => 159
            [categories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 23
                )

            [brand_id] => 38
            [option_set_id] => 
            [option_set_display] => right
            [inventory_level] => 0
            [inventory_warning_level] => 1
            [inventory_tracking] => product
            [reviews_rating_sum] => 0
            [reviews_count] => 0
            [total_sold] => 0
            [fixed_cost_shipping_price] => 0
            [is_free_shipping] => 
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_featured] => 
            [related_products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -1
                )

            [warranty] => 
            [bin_picking_number] => 
            [layout_file] => product.html
            [upc] => 848644000167
            [mpn] => 
            [gtin] => 
            [search_keywords] => 
            [availability] => disabled
            [availability_description] => 
            [gift_wrapping_options_type] => any
            [gift_wrapping_options_list] => Array
                (
                )

            [sort_order] => 0
            [condition] => New
            [is_condition_shown] => 
            [order_quantity_minimum] => 0
            [order_quantity_maximum] => 0
            [page_title] => 
            [meta_keywords] => Array
                (
                )

            [meta_description] => 
            [date_created] => 2020-08-13T22:16:57+00:00
            [date_modified] => 2020-08-13T22:16:57+00:00
            [view_count] => 0
            [preorder_release_date] => 
            [preorder_message] => 
            [is_preorder_only] => 
            [is_price_hidden] => 
            [price_hidden_label] => 
            [custom_url] => 
            [base_variant_id] => 222
            [open_graph_type] => product
            [open_graph_title] => 
            [open_graph_description] => 
            [open_graph_use_meta_description] => 1
            [open_graph_use_product_name] => 1
            [open_graph_use_image] => 1
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 222
                            [product_id] => 234
                            [sku] => FLB108-WG
                            [sku_id] => 
                            [price] => 159
                            [calculated_price] => 159
                            [sale_price] => 0
                            [retail_price] => 0
                            [map_price] => 0
                            [weight] => 0
                            [width] => 0
                            [height] => 0
                            [depth] => 0
                            [is_free_shipping] => 
                            [fixed_cost_shipping_price] => 0
                            [calculated_weight] => 0
                            [purchasing_disabled] => 1
                            [purchasing_disabled_message] => 
                            [image_url] => https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-r932bs4ubb/products/234/images/471/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.1597357017.386.513.jpg?c=1
                            [cost_price] => 0
                            [upc] => 848644000167
                            [mpn] => 
                            [gtin] => 
                            [inventory_level] => 0
                            [inventory_warning_level] => 1
                            [bin_picking_number] => 
                            [option_values] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 471
                            [product_id] => 234
                            [is_thumbnail] => 1
                            [sort_order] => 1
                            [description] => white green calla lily & foliage silk centerpiece, velvety texture, natural appearance green foliage, black stones in acrylic water in heavy 6" square tapered glass vase
                            [image_file] => h/864/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.jpg
                            [url_zoom] => https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-r932bs4ubb/products/234/images/471/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.1597357017.1280.1280.jpg?c=1
                            [url_standard] => https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-r932bs4ubb/products/234/images/471/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.1597357017.386.513.jpg?c=1
                            [url_thumbnail] => https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-r932bs4ubb/products/234/images/471/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.1597357017.220.290.jpg?c=1
                            [url_tiny] => https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-r932bs4ubb/products/234/images/471/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.1597357017.44.58.jpg?c=1
                            [date_modified] => 2020-08-13T22:16:57+00:00
                        )

                )

            [primary_image] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 471
                    [product_id] => 234
                    [is_thumbnail] => 1
                    [sort_order] => 1
                    [description] => white green calla lily & foliage silk centerpiece, velvety texture, natural appearance green foliage, black stones in acrylic water in heavy 6" square tapered glass vase
                    [image_file] => h/864/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.jpg
                    [url_zoom] => https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-r932bs4ubb/products/234/images/471/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.1597357017.1280.1280.jpg?c=1
                    [url_standard] => https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-r932bs4ubb/products/234/images/471/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.1597357017.386.513.jpg?c=1
                    [url_thumbnail] => https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-r932bs4ubb/products/234/images/471/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.1597357017.220.290.jpg?c=1
                    [url_tiny] => https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-r932bs4ubb/products/234/images/471/flb108-wg_zoom__07246.1597357017.44.58.jpg?c=1
                    [date_modified] => 2020-08-13T22:16:57+00:00
                )

            [videos] => Array
                (
                )

            [custom_fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2808
                            [name] => pageId
                            [value] => 47
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2809
                            [name] => notice
                            [value] => FLB108-WG
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2810
                            [name] => summaryImage
                            [value] => /files/imagesSF/product/165/flb108-wg_cat.jpg
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2811
                            [name] => product_productName
                            [value] => Calla Lily & Foliage
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2812
                            [name] => product_title
                            [value] => Calla Lily & Foliage 
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2813
                            [name] => product_productNumber
                            [value] => FLB108-WG
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2814
                            [name] => product_catalogNumber
                            [value] => FLB108-WG
                        )

                    [7] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2815
                            [name] => product_imagePath
                            [value] => files/imagesSF/product/165/flb108-wg_cat.jpg
                        )

                    [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2816
                            [name] => imageBurst
                            [value] => /files/imagesSF/global/bursts/new-bestseller-icon-burst-105.jpg
                        )

                    [9] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2817
                            [name] => acrylicWater
                            [value] => 1
                        )

                    [10] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2818
                            [name] => recipeLocation
                            [value] => right
                        )

                    [11] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2819
                            [name] => prodType
                            [value] => standard
                        )

                    [12] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2820
                            [name] => childTitle
                            [value] => Calla Lily & Foliage
                        )

                    [13] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2821
                            [name] => expShip
                            [value] => 1
                        )

                    [14] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2822
                            [name] => imageBurstLink
                            [value] => /files/filesSF/popups/express-shipping.html
                        )

                    [15] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2823
                            [name] => mobile_name
                            [value] => Calla Lily & Foliage
                        )

                    [16] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2824
                            [name] => googleTitle
                            [value] => Silk Calla Lily Flower Centerpiece with Foliage
                        )

                )

            [bulk_pricing_rules] => Array
                (
                )

            [reviews] => Array
                (
                )

            [options] => Array
                (
                )

            [modifiers] => Array
                (
                )

            [parent_relations] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [meta] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is with the custom_url element:

```
[custom_url] => Array
        (
            [url] => 
            [is_customized] => 
        )
```

This should not be included at all if url is not customized.